# Apply classes to index.html in VueJs on events in components

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using a BS4 template that applies classes to the `<html>` and `<body>` elements based on events on the page.  I have trieddifferent techniques from the Vuejs Class and Style page [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) without success.  I have also tried passing in the value as a prop from App.vue to the Sidebar which I have as a component.

This is where I have got to and the v-bind is not respecting the value at the root level.

**In index.html**

```
<body v-bind:class="{ sidebar-mini: this.$root.sidebarShrunk }">
```

**In main.ts (entry point)**

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    sidebarShrunk: false,
  },
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Updating the value as below does nothing, the class sidebar-mini is not applied.

[image: Updating this value does nothing]

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answers below - this is working - but a further question, is it the best way to do it or can it be refactored a little.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    sidebarShrunk: false,
  },
  watch: {
    sidebarShrunk(sidebarShrunk) {
      if (sidebarShrunk) {
        document.body.classList.add('sidebar-mini');
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('sidebar-mini');
      }
    },
  },
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: I thought $root is used to access data:{} values held in the app's entry point.

Comment: No, I have it though.  `{ 'sidebar-mini': this.$root.sidebarShrunk }`.  The single quotes!  Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

Vue's syntax will only work on `#app` and its children, which apparently doesn't include the body element.

In a case like this, you can use watcher to set the body class using Vanilla Javascript.

```
  data: {
    sidebarShrunk: false,
  },
  watch:{
    sidebarShrunk: 
    {
      handler:function(value) {
        if(value)
          document.body.classList.add("sidebar-mini");
        else
          document.body.classList.remove("sidebar-mini");
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/xqLcuoav/5/

Comment: That was a superhelpful answer, thank you.  Updated it for TypeScript as below.

`new Vue({
  data: {
    sidebarShrunk: false,
  },
  watch: {
    sidebarShrunk(sidebarShrunk) {
      if (sidebarShrunk) {
        document.body.classList.add('sidebar-mini');
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('sidebar-mini');
      }
    },
  },
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');`